# Google Play Store cannot open links for beta alpha release

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play, beta, beta-testing

When i send a link for my beta/alpha release some receivers cannot open the link, not in Whatsapp or mail.
link format: `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.myTestApp.beta`.
I sent the link to my self and failed to open the link as well.

this is the error screen shot
[image]

only if i copy paste the link to my browser it opens

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
it is the Play store app configuration for handling links.

go to the phones **Settings - Apps - Google Play Store - Open by default -
 Open supported links** and set to **Ask every time**
and the link will open by your chosen app Browser or Google Play.

[image]

Comment: Hello, this is a valid workaround, but if your testers are real users u do not necessarely know directly it is hard to explain how to solve a problem clearly coming from latest google update. This should be submitted as a bug

Comment: I reached Google about this issue. They were already aware. They told me it should be adressed by the end of this week. Both for this error screen and for the fact that in the beta opt-in page, after clicking "Become a tester" and "download the app on the play store", the user was not redirected toward the play store but remained in the browser. Let's hope this is true.